# Team achivements on CV

Tags: resume

I have won/attended some contests as team with several different people.

While I write my CV how should I mention this? I don't want to claim that I, alone, won something, but also, I don't like to include names and unrelated data.

I am rather new in the "art" of writing a CV and any advice is appreciated :D

Answer (score 5):

In the *Accomplishments* section of your CV, write the contest name, the name of the team and the prize won as the sub-section header, and in the description, describe the **task that were *yours*** in the team for that contest:

> **Ludum Dare 32, Team Alphabird, 2nd prize**
>
> My role in the team was to make sure that the graphics style was coherent throughout the game. The main challenges I faced were: decide of an art style that would fit within the timeframe of the contest, and guide the two other artists in following the base concept.